# Is there any typescript/javascript postgres ORM that supports composite types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, orm

I am considering moving from a nosql database to postgres.

My nosql database has documents that have deeply nested objects. Those deeply nested objects are not related to any other models (they are self contained).

I know postgres and sql has `CREATE_TYPE` where you can define custom types and create nested objects that way. However, I have not seen an ORM for typescript or javascript that supports such functionality out of the box. Is there one out there and I'm simply blind?

I know I can use the json type with transformers but I don't think that will let me write nice migrations or good queries.